# Way to group resources

Tags: android, android-resources

I'd like to group my drawables in some way that doesn't involve some crazy approach (for example reflection on the generated `R` class).

For example I have 10 types of some object in a game. I'd like to load them all into an array without actually copying:

```
enemy[0] = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.enemy_image_0)
enemy[0].set....
enemy[1] = resources.getDrawable.....
```

Is there some way to group them and load in a loop? Any way to do that without getting into how `R` is generated and changing its structure?

Comment: Once you actually have the solution could you please post the line of code - I looked at getRessources().getIdentifier(name,defType,defPackage) - wouldn't know what to actually put there... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Is there some way to group them and load in a loop?

Use `getIdentifier()` on the `Resources` object (which you typically get via `getResources()` on your activity or other `Context`).

Since this, under the covers, uses a "crazy approach" (specifically "reflection on the generated `R` class"), and since reflection is not especially speedy, please cache these values where possible.